# Opções para gerar documentação de bibliotecas javascript

Tags: node.js, documentação, grunt

Atualmente tenho usado muito o `jsdoc3` com o `docstrap`, contudo requer uma quantidade grande de bibliotecas de terceiros para gerar documentação com `node` e `grunt`, alguém conhece uma alternativa robusta(que possui um nível de especificação igual ou até melhor e que contenha menos dependências para a geração da documentação)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exite algumas outras bibliotecas que geram documentação a partir de código javascript além do jsdoc3, porém a maioria vai exigir que você configure o ambiente para que ela funcione. Leve em conta que além de ler o código fonte, uma biblioteca com essa função teria que salvar muitos arquivos da documentação final, e isso é bem complicado de fazer com Javascript puro dentro de um navegador ou então usando apenas arquivo .bat ou .sh.

Eu pessoalmente prefiro o jsdoc3, mas se realmente quer testar outras alternativas (que pessoalmente não testei mas sei que existem), segue uma lista

- [jGrouseDoc](http://code.google.com/p/jgrousedoc/)
- [jsd100](http://code.google.com/p/jsd100/)
- [DocumentJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs/DocumentJS.html#&who=DocumentJS)
- [JSDoc Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/)

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso e recomendo o http://yui.github.io/yuidoc é muito fácil de usar e bastante completo.

Ele gera a documentação à partir dos comentários no código, num formato parecido com o JSDoc:

#### Classes

```
/**
* Descrição da classe.
*
* @class MinhaClasse
* @constructor
*/
```

#### Métodos

```
/**
* Descrição do método.  Como qualquer outro comentário,
* podem ocorrer quebras de linha sem problema.
*
* @method nomeMetodo
* @param {String} foo Parâmetro 1
* @param {Object} config Objeto de configuração
* @param {String} config.name Nome do objeto de config
* @param {Function} config.callback Callback do objeto de configuração
* @param {Boolean} [extra=false] Parâmetro extra, opcional
* @return {Boolean} Retorna true se bem sucedido
*/
```

Para gerar a documentação, basta rodar `yuidoc <camindo de entrada>`.
Para mais opções, veja [a documentação em inglês](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/args/index.html).